# How to implement generic control validation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have recently been trying to get into the habit of using MVVM design patterns within the project im working on with the aim of decoupling the various modules in the app and make it suitable for unit testing.

I have moved onto input validation. I am implementing IDataErrorInfo in my ViewModel...this seems to work pretty well for TextBox.

**I'm currently trying to work out how to implement IDataErrorInfo on the ListBox control which is bound to an ObservableCollection of custom objects. Problem is each row (ListBoxItem) updates the model directly so my IDataErrorInfo implementation in the ViewModel is bypassed.** So the way i see it i can do one of two things -

1) Create a secondary ViewModel (to represent ListBoxItems) which i use to populate the Observable Collection  and implement IDataErrorInfo on that.

2) Implement IDataErrorInfo on my Model. However, since the ViewModel is mainly used to relay references from my Model i would then probably consider moving all my IDataErrorInfo implementation to my Model class for consistency...

What would you do?

Also...any advice on creating reusable validation methods which i can easily apply to any type of Control?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would you do?

The first option, of course - create a secondary view model for list items. You shouldn't implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your models, because this is UI-specific functional.

> reusable validation methods which i can easily apply to any type of Control

You're misunderstanding MVVM. `IDataErrorInfo` is intended for view model validation, not the *control* validation.

Comment: Possibly a failing in my communication skills...Haha.When i asked about reusable validation methods i was referring to the whole setup. So, i can implement IDataErrorInfo in my ViewModel but i also have a custom template for each control which sets the Validation.ErrorTemplate. Seems I'm having to add a lot of code to the top of my xaml for validation - sure i can put it in a resource dictionary but is this optimal? Im also aware there are different mechanisms to validate data ValidationRules, even ValueConverters...So was seeking some advice on this.